# Generating Function: $50 Change

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, generating-functions

How many ways to collect $50 from 15 distinct people, if the first one gives either 0, 1 or 8 and the other 14 give either 1 or 5.

I started putting writing the function as $f(x)=(1+x+x^8)*(x+x^5)^{14}$

I understand that what we're looking for is the coefficient of $x^{50}$.

How should I proceed?

My first idea would've been to only check for the coefficients of $x^{50}, x^{49}$ and $x^{42}$ for $g(x)=(x+x^5)^{14}$ for the cases if the first person gave respectively 0,1 or 8 bucks and add the results together.

Would that be correct? Could I do it without adding each case separately?

Also, any hint about how to simplify and/or proceed would be a great help!

Comment: The generating function is correct.  A computer can simplify this immediately with no issue.  Are you trying to simplify this by hand? Why? If you insist on doing this by hand, then instead of looking at $(x+x^5)^{14}$, look instead at $x^{14}(1+x^4)^{14}$. You should be able to reason then that the first person must give $0$ or $8$. In the case that the first person gives $0$, how many of the remaining people gave one?  How many ways could that happen? In the case the first person gives $8$, how many of the remaining people gave one? How many ways could that happen. Use binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is fine. In order to obtain the result manually, it is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ in a series.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^{50}]}&\color{blue}{(1+x+x^8)(x+x^5)^{14}}\\
> &=[x^{50}](1+x+x^8)x^{14}(1+x^4)^{14}\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^{36}](1+x+x^8)\sum_{j=0}^{14}\binom{14}{j}x^{4j}\tag{2}\\
> &=([x^{36}]+[x^{35}]+[x^{28}])\sum_{j=0}^{14}\binom{14}{j}x^{4j}\tag{3}\\
> &=\binom{14}{9}+0+\binom{14}{7}\tag{4}\\
> &=2002+0+3432\\
> &=\color{blue}{5434}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we factor out $x^{14}$.
- In (2) we use the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$ of the *coeffcient of* operator and apply the *[binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)*.
- In (3) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the same rule as in (2).
- In (4) we select the coefficients accordingly and observe that only multiples of $4$ of the exponent provide non-zero contributions.

*Hint:* Small detail due to a comment. In the following we successively skip summands which do not contribute to the coefficient of $x^k$.
\begin{align*}
[x^{36}]\sum_{j=0}^{14}\binom{14}{j}x^{4j}&=[x^{36}]\sum_{j=9}^{9}\binom{14}{j}x^{4j}=[x^{36}]\binom{14}{9}x^{36}=\binom{14}{9}\\
[x^{35}]\sum_{j=0}^{14}\binom{14}{j}x^{4j}&=[x^{35}]0=0
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very, very much, that was very concise! Could you maybe expand on your 4th transformation? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @user452306: Some details added. Regards,